# How to show a done button depending on the edition status of a tableview, from a UITableView extension?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I wrote a UITableView extension that would allow the reordering of cells after holding the tableview.

So the tableView goes edit mode as expected but what I would like to do is to add a Done button in the navigation bar of a viewController, when the tableView is being edited and that would end the edit mode when tapped.

How can I show/hide this button in viewController according to if the tableView being edited or not in UITableView extension?

that is my extension:

```
import UIKit

extension UITableView {
    func addLongPressToTableView() {
        let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onLongPressGesture(sender:)))
        longPress.minimumPressDuration = 0.8 // optional
        self.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
    }
    
    @objc func onLongPressGesture(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        if (sender.state == .began) {
            self.isEditing = true
            self.setEditing(true, animated: false)
            UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .light).impactOccurred()
        }
    }
}

// ViewController, hide/show editButtonItem (done button?)
// navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [addButton, editButtonItem]
```

Comment: Can you enable your button when the long press stars, then set the table's editing to false after the user taps on done button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UITableViewDelegate provides support for coordinating editing.  Use the following two delegate methods to respond to changes in the editing state.

`func tableView(UITableView, willBeginEditingRowAt: IndexPath)`

`func tableView(UITableView, didEndEditingRowAt: IndexPath?)`

Comment: I'd also not implement the long-press support through an extension on UIableview, espoecially when you are binding to an explicit selector.  It would be better implemented on the VC, either directly or through a protocol.

Comment: the two methods didn't trigger, worked with instead:     override func setEditing (_ editing:Bool, animated:Bool)
        {
            super.setEditing(editing, animated:animated)
            if self.isEditing {
                navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [editButtonItem]
            } else {
                navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [addThemeButton]
            }
        }

Comment: How would you not coding it in ViewController and use protocol? Idea would be to easily apply this feature to any tableview